# How to create a class library project and refer assemblies to that project using T4 templates

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I started looking into T4 templates which helps developer to generate code.

1. But is there any way to generate class library project (as we do in
   visual studio) using T4 templates? If so, could you please suggest
   some sites?
2. Is it possible to add assemblies as a reference to a project
   using T4 templates?

I went through this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and this [link](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/)

But I did not get the answers for the above. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: What's do you mean by class library project? Definitely you can use T4 in class library project. Do you want to use T4 generate project itself?

Comment: Yes I want to use T4 to generate project itself

Answer (score 0):

A class library project is just a .csproj file, and its accompanying files (.cs files, .config files, etc.) Basically they are plain text files which have to conform to a specific format. Which means that yes, you can create a class library project using T4.

The class library project file (which defines all external references, the directories and files in the project etc) is actually an [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) file. You can find the structure of Visual Studio project files [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx). Better yet, you can create a simple class library project, then open the .csproj file with a text editor and see what's in it.

Just to demonstrate, I created a simple class library project with Visual Studio 2015. This is the structure:

[image]

So basically you have

```
\Properties
\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
\Directory1
\Directory1\Directory1Class1.cs
\Class1.cs
\Class2.cs
\packages.config
```

You can see the internals of the `DummyClassLibrary.csproj` file in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/taylan/a026b45ae237c9aa1d8a).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any csproj templates for T4 anywhere so you might have to write the templates yourself.